# displaying Laurent polynomials nicely

Tags: output-formatting

I have some 2-variable Laurent polynomials in $q$ and $t$, and I'd like to collect powers of $q$ and display them without using fractions, and to sort the terms by the power of $q$. For example, I'd like to display $(t-t^{-1})q^{-1} + (t^{-1})q$, instead of $(t-\frac 1 t)\frac 1 q + \frac q t$ which is what Mathematica wants to output.

Is there a nice way to do this? Right now I'm applying the function

> StandardForm[# /. Power[expr_, r_?Negative] :> Superscript[expr, r]] &

to the polynomials I'd like to display, which makes negative powers display as exponents. But the problem is that Mathematica then doesn't sort the terms correctly, since it doesn't recognize the "Superscript" as a power.

Answer (score 2):

```
f[subexpr_, var_] := Sort@Which[
  NumberQ[subexpr], {subexpr, {var, 0}},
  Head[subexpr] === Power && subexpr[[1]] == var, {1, List @@ subexpr},
  MemberQ[subexpr, var], List @@ subexpr /. var -> {var, 1},
  True, List @@ # /. Power[var, r_] :> List[var, r] &@subexpr
 ]
f2[expr_, var_] := Plus @@ (#1 Superscript[var, #2[[2]]] & @@@ 
    Sort[f[#, var] & /@ (List @@ expr), #1[[2, 2]] < #2[[2, 2]] &])
expr1 = Series[1/Sin[x]^10, {x, 0, 2}] // Normal
expr2 = (t - t^-1) q^-1 + (t^-1) q
f2[expr1, x]
f2[expr2, q]
```